# Retrieve typeform form data in embed mode

Tags: javascript, typeform

I've seen that I can hook up to the `onSubmit` event with the following code:

```
typeformEmbed.makeWidget(this.$el, 'https://pptt.typeform.com/to/S70gmy', {
      onSubmit: event => {
        console.log('event.onSubmit', event)
      }
    })
```

However, that event is undefined, like Typeform, it only sends the event out without the form data

Then there's this way:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
      if(event.data.type == 'form-submit')
        // your business logic here
    }, false);
```

But I can't find the form data there.

Is this possible? I'd like to send the typeform data elsewhere, or append it to another normal form that I have.

Comment: See my reply here for some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75304449/7347492

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are using [Typeform Embed SDK](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/).

Different ways to do this:

- have a webhook on this form, it will get pinged when the form is submitted and there you will have access to the whole payload of the answer. [Doc](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/example-payload/)
- on the onSubmit action, get the response id and call [Typeform Responses API](https://developer.typeform.com/responses/) to find the corresponding response.

```js
const reference = typeformEmbed.makePopup(
  'https://admin.typeform.com/to/PlBzgL',
  {
    onSubmit: function (event) {
      console.log(event.response_id)
    }
  }
)
```

I hope it helps.
We are looking at making improvements at this SDK in the near future.

*(edit: 25 August 2020, the Embed SDK now supports this usecase)*

Comment: Thanks you, couldnt find anything but wanted a confirmation. Paperform is a decent alternative

Comment: I just check their doc, and you are right they do offer this feature. 

It might come soon to Typeform Embed SDK thanks to feedback like yours 

Comment: This is ridiculous. I created my Typeform, embedded it in my website and now find that you can't get the data from the Typeform itself to the page itself ? This product is useless for serious development in its current form.

Comment: I updated my response because Typeform updated the SDK recently and the onSubmit callback now contains a way to retrieve the response id.
Augusto, happy to chat in private if you have any question/feedback

Comment: @NicolasGrenié I've just tested the new `onSubmit` callback. I tried to get the answers with the Responses API but faced 2 problems: there are CORS policy that prevent the call to be made on the frontend and the answers are not immediately available when I called the API. I had to implement a retry logic to retry the call until the answers were available. It's a real pain to use right now.. Why don't you provide the answers directly in the callback? It would solve both problems and would be much easier to integrate.

Comment: @Kerumen it's for security reason... otherwise anybody could embed anybody typeform and access to the responses collected, this is not safe.

Comment: @Kerumen, a few ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75304449/7347492