# Retrieve typeform form data in not embed mode

Tags: typeform

I'm using Typeforms(not embedded mode) and looking for a way to retrieve form data. I tested many ways and none worked.
There are a couple of solution about embed mode like:
[Retrieve typeform form data in embed mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59049553/retrieve-typeform-form-data-in-embed-mode)

But this doesn't work for me.
Does anyone know how I can capture form field values at submission? I don't want to pass this information in the query string, I'm looking for another solution.
Here is the page that I'm working on:
https://techobloc1.pro.typeform.com/to/teQj56wI

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Typeform Responses API](https://developer.typeform.com/responses/) to retrieve the response. If you want to process data on each submission [Typeform Webhooks API](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/) will be more suitable.

If you want to execute custom client-side code on submit that only possible for embedded forms (using the `onSubmit` handler as explained in [the other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59049553/retrieve-typeform-form-data-in-embed-mode)).

I would suggest to embed your typeform. Then you can get the response ID in `onSubmit` handler, pass that to your own API endpoint and use the ID to retrieve specific response via Responses API. I wrote a blog post about this approach: [Integrate Typeform with Next.js](https://medium.com/typeforms-engineering-blog/integrate-typeform-with-next-js-b27a5306bfbb)

Comment: Hi Mathio, Thank you for getting back to me. I tested Webhooks API and it just returns the form information and not the element information. I'm looking for a way to get the value that the user put for the email address, first name, and last name, ....  
Do you think it is feasible?

Comment: Yes. Both Responses and Webhooks APIs can provide responses (data submitted by your users). Depends on your use case which one will fit you better. With Webhook API the data will be delivered to your endpoint on form submit. In case of Responses API you need to query the API endpoint yourself (eg. from your own server).

Comment: I just realized that Webhook sends the form information to an endpoint and I can specify this endpoint to receive data. (It looks like we can send the data to a server)
I'm using Google tag manager and using that I can see when the form gets submitted. do you think we can somehow collect this data using GTM client side? 

Special thanks for for help

Comment: I am no GTM expert, but I dont think you can capture typeform responses with GTM. You will need to use one of the APIs or one of the integrations: https://www.typeform.com/connect/